# I am creating a Pop up in Html using table and css but I see gap between the two cells in table row when I zoom the page to 110% in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am using a table to display the arrow and a dialogue box. When I zoom the page to 110% there is a gap between the arrow and the box. This is seen only on Chrome.
In the computed section I see the `border-right-width` is set to `11.9886px` when zoomed to 110%. Which should ideally be `12px` which is mentioned as `border-width: 10px 12px 10px 0 !important;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
        }

        table {
            border-spacing: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: none;
        }

        td {
            padding: 0px;
        }

        .box {
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            background: white;
        }

        .arrow-left {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            border-right-color: white;
            border-width: 10px 12px 10px 0 !important;
            border-color: transparent;
            border-style: solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="tableCustom">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="arrow-left" style="border-right-color:white"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="box"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Screenshot of the gap
[image: Screenshot of the gap]

Comment: If you don't have tabular data, don't use the `table` tag

Answer (score 1):

No need for a table, the table cells are going to come with their own calculation which as you have found can behave awkwardly on zoom. Tables should also be avoided for layout. Use them for tabular data only.

Use a simple element instead

```css
body {background-color:#999; padding-left:5em;}

/*Style the box as needed*/
.dialog-box{max-width: 15em;
  min-height: 5em;
  background-color:white;
  /*Needed to postion our arrow relative to this box*/
  position:relative;  
}

/*The arrow, for more on CSS  triangles see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/*/
.dialog-box:before{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid white;
    content:'';
    /*Position the triangle, 10px is the width and height of the triangle set above.*/
    position:absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top:calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog-box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add some property on " .arrow-left" class

```
left: 1px;
position: relative;
```